# How can I receive focus and select event in my HTML custom element

Tags: javascript, focus, custom-element

I am building a custom HTML element.

The custom HTML element extends a table cell element.

I have included an input textbox in this custom element.

When the custom element got a focus or select event, I want the input text box to get these events.

Here is my code:

```js
class DateCell extends HTMLTableCellElement {
    constructor() {
     super();
     this.textBox = document.createElement("input");
     this.textBox.type = "text";
     this.appendChild(this.textBox);
     $(this).addClass("borderCell");
     $(this).addClass("dateCell");
    }
    focus(e)
    {
     this.textBox.focus();
    }
    select(e)
    {
     this.textBox.select();
    }    
    set textContent(t)
    {
     this.textBox.value = t;
    }
    get textContent()
    {
     return this.textBox.value ;
    }
    set value(v) 
    {
     this.textBox.value = v;
     switch (v)
     {
      case "a":
        this.textBox.className="aShiftColor";
        break;
      case "b":
        this.textBox.className="bShiftColor";
        break;
      case "c":
        this.textBox.className="cShiftColor";
        break;  
     }
    }
    get value() {
     return this.textBox.value;
    }
   }
   customElements.define('datacell-string',
    DateCell, {
     extends: 'td'
    });
   $(document).ready(function() {
    var t = document.createElement("table");
    var row = t.insertRow(t.rows);
    var cell1 = new DateCell();
    var cell2 = new DateCell();
    var cell3 = new DateCell();
    row.appendChild(cell1);
    row.appendChild(cell2);
    row.appendChild(cell3);
    
    $(cell1).val("a");
    cell2.value = "c";
    cell2.select();
    $(cell3).val("b");
    $(cell3).focus();
    $(document.body).append(t);
    $("td").each(function(){
     console.log(this.value);
    });
   });
```

```css
td input[type="text"]   
   {
    //color:white;
    border:none;
    //border:1px solid black;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   td input[type="text"]:focus 
   {
    outline: none;
   }
   table 
   {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
   }   
   .aShiftColor
   {
    background-color:#ff99cc;
   }
   .borderCell
   {
    border:1px solid #e0e0e0;
   }
   .bShiftColor
   { 
    background-color:#ffffcc;
   }
   .cShiftColor
   {
    background-color:#ccffcc;
   }
   .dateCell
   {
    margin:0px;
    width:25px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:17px;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately, none of these input boxes is selected or on focus.

Answer (score 0):

After several trials, I found that because of all DateCells are not connected to attached to DOM, so the "select" and "focus" effect is not shown.

Therefore, I changed the following code:

```
   ..............
   cell2.select();
   $(cell3).val("b");
   $(cell3).focus();
   $(document.body).append(t);
```

to

```
  ..............
  $(cell3).val("b");
  $(document.body).append(t);
  cell2.select();
  $(cell3).focus();
```

, then it works!